# How to insert a rupee symbol in table using Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I want to insert an ₹ symbol in my table as the currency symbol of India. I tried using the &#8377 html code for the rupee symbol and unicode U+0930, but it is not showing me the rupee symbol.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you see when you run, select E'\u0930';
What encoding do you have?

Comment: What is it showing you, then? And how are you doing the insert.

Comment: hello john, INSERT INTO currency_mst (currency_id,currency_name,currency_symbol,status,created_by,updated_by)
VALUES(2,'INR','&#8377;',1,'Nagesh','Nagesh');

Comment: using above query i try to insert ..bt in the table same "&#8377;" this value is printed as a currency symbol. i want to insert rupee symbol in my table..

Comment: Don't use the html symbol. Use the unicode style, ie, E\u0930 or U&\u0930. This is documented here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html

Comment: i tried both E\u0930 and U&\u0930 it again showing me the same as it is. and with this 1 warning is generating which is as below..      UPDATE currency_mst SET currency_symbol = 'U&\u0930' WHERE currency_symbol = 'u0930'; 
WARNING:  nonstandard use of escape in a string literal
LINE 1: UPDATE currency_mst SET currency_symbol = 'U&\u0930' WHERE c...
                                                  ^
HINT:  Use the escape string syntax for escapes, e.g., E'\r\n'.

Comment: when i use below query to update my symbol                        UPDATE currency_mst SET currency_symbol = U&'\u0930' WHERE currency_symbol = 'u0930';   It showing an error msg which is below...

Comment: ERROR:  unsafe use of string constant with Unicode escapes
LINE 1: UPDATE currency_mst SET currency_symbol = U&'\u0930' WHERE c...
                                                  ^
DETAIL:  String constants with Unicode escapes cannot be used when standard_conforming_strings is off.

********** Error **********

ERROR: unsafe use of string constant with Unicode escapes
SQL state: 0A000
Detail: String constants with Unicode escapes cannot be used when standard_conforming_strings is off.
Character: 43

Comment: Suggest you read the docs page I listed. That error will become clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
select E'\u20B9'||' '||4000
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is very old question even then my answer is as below (hope it may help some one) -

Need to insert UNICODE value of any symbol and here question is about INR symbol, menas we need to insert INR unicode symbol into db like this -

```
INSERT INTO CURRENCY (CUR_CODE, CUR_SYMBOL, CUR_NAME) VALUES('INR', UNISTR('\u20B9'), 'Indian Rupee');
```

after that execute normal select statement -

```
SELECT CUR_CODE, CUR_SYMBOL, CUR_NAME FROM CURRENCY;
```

and we will see the Rupee symbol.